# What's the term for a cord that doesn't fit perfectly in the socket

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What do you call a power cord for example that doesn't fit perfectly in the power socket and you can move it if you press it on the side. I used *fiddle* but am not sure if that's the correct term.

Comment: Perhaps 'dangerous'?

Comment: Are you after an adjective or a noun?

Comment: *Fiddle* in the sense "wiggle from side to side" rather than "violin" is normally a verb.

Comment: Unclear to me what is 'unclear' about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases of technical use, it is referred as a *poor fit*.

[dictionary com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fit):

> The coat is a poor fit.

[OxfordCollocationDict](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=fit):

> The door was a poor fit and didn't open properly.

Comment: Thank you. Would "the power cord is a poor fit for the power outlet" work?

Comment: Yes, kind of. More precisely, the *plug* is a poor fit for the *socket*. Strictly speaking, 'cord' is just the cable, though the entire accessory as such is also commercially referred to as a 'cord' ('power cord').